# RMarkdown from server file

Tags: r-markdown, blastula

I am transferring code from my computer to a server and there is a problem with the reference to the markdown file.

First, this code works:

```
> blastula::render_email('C:/Users/Me/Desktop/markdown_code.Rmd')
```

But when the Rmd file is in the server, there is an error:

```
> blastula::render_email('//server01/Data/markdown_code.Rmd')
pandoc.exe: markdown_code.knit.md: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
```

I found out that it has something to do with the server address. When I try to knit the markdown itself manually in RStudio, I get this error:

```
Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\server01": The specified path is invalid
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="\\server01/..": The specified path is invalid
```

The markdown itself is a very simple code:

````
title: title
output: blastula::blastula_email
---
Text
```{r print, echo=FALSE}
df
```                               #
````

Is there a special syntax for referencing the markdown file in the server or what could be the solution for this?

Comment: a lot of times, this is becuase Pandoc doesn't have folder permissions to read/write/edit/execute the file(s) on the server. It says it doesn't exist, because it doesn't have permissions to see the folder contents. And Rmarkdown needs the main files inside the root directory, and when they aren't, like server/client types, is causes permission issues.

Comment: that's good to know! but the next questions is, how can I grant Pandoc the permissions?